# Html.DropDownList on select disable some text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to razor pages and web in general.  I have this drop down menu using DropDownList() in my cshtml file.  Now when the user selects one of the items I want to disable certain textbox on the same razer page but I haven't found any info on how to do this specifically with Html.DropDownList.  Below is my drop down list of 3 items which is working fine but I need to detect user selection.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("Location", Html.GetEnumSelectList<InventoryAdjustment.Pages.CreateRecordModel.locations>(), "Select Scan Option", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Does it means, when the user select any item from dropdown you want to disable textbox based on value selected in dropdown right? Could you please share which textbox you would like to disable?

Comment: Nevermind figured out I had to use @onchange in parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the user selects one of the items I want to disable certain
> textbox on the same razer page but I haven't found any info on how to
> do this specifically with Html.DropDownList. Below is my drop down
> list of 3 items which is working fine but I need to detect user
> selection.

In order to disable textbox based on your selectlist or dropdown value, you should use  `@onchange` attribute and write a funcation within it and finally pass `this.value` to your function,  and it will fetch the selected value at the same time would call the function.

Finally, you can write conditional according to your value to disable the textbox inside the function.

Let's have a look in practice how we can achieve that:

Razor cshtml:

```
public class LocationSelectListDisableTextboxModel : PageModel
    {
        public static List<SelectListItem> GetAll()
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "0",  Text = "Please Select Value" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Location-A" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Location-B" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Location-C" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Disable Textbox" }
              
            };
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            selectListItems = GetAll();
        }
    }
```

Razor cshtml.cs:

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemoApp.Pages.LocationSelectListDisableTextboxModel
@{
}


Location DropDown: @Html.DropDownList("Location", Model.selectListItems, null, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "DisableTextboxByDropdownValue(this.value)" })
<hr />
TextBox:
<br />
<input type="text" id="myTextbox" class="form-control" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function DisableTextboxByDropdownValue(locationId) {

        alert(locationId);
        if (locationId == 4) {
            $("#myTextbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {

            $("#myTextbox").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#myTextbox").focus();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can [refer to official document to know details on how validation works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#validation).